# Segmentation fault on C++ HelloWorld program when ran on command line but not Visual Studio Code (Windows 10)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, msys2

I can run a C++ program through VisualStudioCode but if I try to run it from commandline I get a segmentation fault. The issue seems to come from C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\libstdc++-6.dll

Update: Deleting libstdc++-6.dll from C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\ allows the program to run on command line. Not entirely sure why.

I have looked through my ENV variables for anything wrong and found nothing. I installed the compiler following this article, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw. It worked for compiling the c programs I wanted. I used the default setting so my path variable is C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin. I tried moving the variable up the list like other posts suggest but nothing changed. I have this variable as a part of both user and system path variables. I have also tried changing it from C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin to C:\msys64\mingw64\bin.

When I step through the program using gdb this is the result:

> Reading symbols from helloWorld...
> (gdb) run
> Starting program: C:\Users\user\Desktop\Code\C++\helloWorld.exe
> [New Thread 21684.0x52f8]
> [New Thread 21684.0x4c6c]
> [New Thread 21684.0x3b10]
>
> Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> 0x00007ff8c5c363a6 in ?? () from C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\libstdc++-6.dll

The command I am using to compile the program:

> g++ -g -o helloWorld helloWorld.cpp

> $ ./helloWorld

> Segmentation fault

The odd thing is that when I tried running the code using VSC it actually worked. I'm wondering why it would work using VSC but not commandline and how I can make it work on commandline.

A couple years ago I installed cygwin64. I have no idea if that is relevant or could interfere somehow

[The VSC option I select to run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCFjm.png)

This is my helloWorld code just for reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work for me. Try deleting the `./helloWorld` executable, then build and run again.

Comment: Actually, it looks like `gdb` is executing `helloWorld.exe`, so you may not be running the same program.

Comment: Note: The Command window loads the path when it is started, so changing the system path requires, at a minimum, restarting the command window you're using to run the program after the path is updated.

Comment: Sounds like you are 90% of the way there. but note that moving the msys2 DLL ahead of the git dll in the path will probably break git.

Comment: *"Deleting libstdc++-6.dll"* You probably broke Git by doing this. The correct solution is to configure your build system to copy this dll from `C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin` to the build directory.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I did some basic testing for Git and it seems to be working fine. I just tested creating a new repo and pushing to it remotely. In what ways could this break manifest? I'm also not sure how to configure my build system as I don't even know what my build system is. Ill look into it.

Comment: *"seems to be working fine"* That's lucky. But what you did to Git is the same thing that your own program was subject to before: not having the correct .dll accessible to it, and instead using a .dll with the same name that happened to be in PATH, which sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't. *"I don't even know what my build system is."* You're not using one. :) Either start using one (Make or CMake or something else), or manually copy the dlls once, or write a script to run the compiler and also `cp` the dlls.

Comment: We call this DLL Hell for a reason. It's easy to get into Hell, but once you're in.... The best thing to do is carefully curate what does into the system path. When a Tutorial says "Just add it in the Path!" question that tutorial and do some deeper research to find out how to avoid it. This is critical for stuff like the MinGW DLLs. There are a lot of tools built on MinGW, and it's naive thinking to expect them all to be using the same version.